# My rails app's redis cache on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I am trying to use Redis on Heroku.

I set like the following on initialiers.

```
redis_url = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0/myapp"
RedisApp::Application.config.cache_store = :redis_store, redis_url
RedisApp::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, redis_server: redis_url
```

session works fine. But fragment cache gives an error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)):
```

I believe that the cache is trying to access wrong location.

What mistake did I make?

Thanks.

Comment: can you confirm you have a `REDISTOGO_URL` config var set on your heroku app?

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that. I checked it with heroku config. And I successfully pulled it from a controller.

Comment: I have experienced exactly the same problem with Redis Cloud add-on but only when I tried to set global TTL. Without expires_in key it works pretty well. Also Redis Cloud has 20 Mb for free.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I have the same problem on the heroku. It  seems like ENV is not loading properly

Answer (score 0):

You must change the `ENV` variable for `ENV["REDIS_URL"]` and it will use the one provided by Heroku itself

Answer (score 0):

Inside `config/environments/production.rb` set it like [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-rediscachestore):

```rb
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
```

Don't for get to add the redis gem too if you haven't already:

```
gem 'redis'
```

From the [Caching with Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-rediscachestore) Rails Guide.